# Overriding Arrays.toString() Method

Tags: java, arrays, overriding, tostring

I'm just wondering, is it possible to override toString() method of class java.util.Arrays. I'm making a project on our class and I plan to output my arrays instead of

> [33, 12, 98] to [033, 012, 098]

I'm just wondering if it is possible to do that without overriding Arrays.toString() method.

Thank you for your assistance :)

Comment: Just write the method in your own class, and call that method instead of Arrays.toString(). Why would you want to make the method Arrays.toString() do something other than what its documentation says it does?

Comment: By *overwrite*, I hope you mean **override**.

Comment: It's not possible, fortunately.

Comment: Just pad the contents with leading zeroes accordingly and print the array as it is.

Comment: as it is static there is no way to override, nor is it needed - this method is normally not called *automatically*, so you just can call any other method (created for that). Or `Arrays.stream($1).mapToObj(i -> String.format("%03d", i)).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[","]"))`

Comment: What is the expectation for the padding? To add ONE leading 0 or to left-pad to length of 3?

Answer (score 9):

You can't **override** the Arrays.toString(). Instead you can write your own *generic* method by appending a leading 0, something like :

```
public static <T> String toString(T arr[]) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(s -> "0" + s).collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

And simply call it :

```
Integer arr[] = {13, 14, 15};
System.out.println(toString(arr));
```

---

If you are dealing with a primitive data-type (assuming only an `int` here), then the *toString()* would  look like :

```
public static String toString(int arr[]) {
   return Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(s -> "0" + s)
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As others already mentioned, it is not possible to overwrite `Arrays.toString`. The solution is to write own code to create the string, for example so with Java 8 streams:

```
int[] array = { 33, 12, 98 };
String result = 
      Arrays.stream(array)                            // stream of ints
            .boxed()                                  // converted to Integers
            .map(String::valueOf)                     // converted to String
            .map(s -> StringUtils.leftPad(s, 3, "0")) // left-padded
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));       // appended together with , as separator


Assert.assertEquals("[033, 012, 098]", result);
```

Comment: This requires a dependency on Apache commons.

Comment: Yes, it does. Of course, if that is a problem, one could go for String.format("%03d"). I personally would prefer Apache Commons StringUtils.leftPad or Guava Strings.padStart function.

Comment: You should use [`joining(", ", "[", "]")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Comment: @Andreas: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like a fixed-width field filled with leading zeros, you can use `String.format()` with a format symbol like `%03d`, using just standard Java libraries.

For example:

```
static String toString(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%03d", i))    // <-- Format
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]"));
}
```

With the input below, the result is *[033, 012, 098, 123, 001]*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myarray = new int[] { 33, 12, 98, 123, 1 };
    String s = toString(myarray);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: You should use [`joining(", ", "[", "]")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-). No need for a `StringBuilder`.